# Bash iterate over regex matches

Tags: regex, bash

I want to prepare a script to analyze some log file in bash.
Lines in the file look like: `... Error(...), Error(...)...`
I wanted to do something like:
`if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]`
to iterate over multiple matches but I cannot find the way to do so.
Any ideas?

PS:  `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` is not a solution since it contains group match information, not the matches itself.

Comment: show some fragment of your log file and the expected result

Comment: Try: `if $(grep -q $regex <<<"$line"); then <something>; fi`

Comment: You can use `grep -o`

Comment: I have been looking for a solution like this, but it is quicker to admit that if you need a universal solution, `grep -o 'pattern'` is the easiest. Common "work arounds" for Bash are splitting the string with whitespaces, and iterating over the array to check each item against a pattern that cannot match 2 or more whitespace-separated chunks that way.

Comment: @Jahid @WiktorStribizew fyi `grep -o` is broken on Mac.

Comment: @user3932000 : You can use GNU grep `ggrep` from homebrew

Answer (score 0):

If you pull together all your mentioned snippets, you'll just need the Error regex and a while-loop to get each Error within a line:

```
#!/bin/bash

line="... Error(foo), Error(bar), Error(foobar) ..."

regex="Error\(([^)]+)\)"

while [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; do
    echo "Found match: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    # Remove the found match from the line to continue searching
    line=${line#*${BASH_REMATCH[1]}}
done
```

Test it online: https://onlinegdb.com/MUPXbg7ZyM